# How to target a column and convert it to percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse, gt

Im trying to convert the count_contribution column to a percentage

here is my code

```
Combined%>%
   group_by(`Processing Server`)%>%
   summarise(Transaction_count = n(), Face_value = sum(FaceValue))%>%
   mutate(Count_contribution = Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count))%>%
  fmt_percent(columns = Count_contribution,decimals = 1)
```

in the Face_value column, I want to add currency

and in the count column, I want to add (,) to the count

I want it to look like this table

[image]

This is the error I'm getting below in markdown.

Error: The object to `data` is not a `gt_tbl` object.

Comment: Where did `fmt_percent` come from, and what about it doesn't work?

Comment: it came from gt package, is there any other package that one can use to achieve this

Comment: Probably, but it's hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying `fmt_percent` or any other `gt` command, change the dataframe with `gt()` function. You can use `fmt_number` to add commas to number.

Using `mtcars` as an example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl)%>%
  summarise(Transaction_count = n() * 100, mpg = sum(mpg)) %>%
  mutate(Count_contribution = Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count)) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_percent(columns = Count_contribution,decimals = 1) %>%
  fmt_number(columns = Transaction_count)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need can be done with just `dplyr`. But if you to export the table elsewhere, Ronak's guide to using `gt` should be enough.

```
library(dplyr)
##This is just to recreate your data set 
Combined <- structure(list(`Processing Server` = c("linode", "vpn-100", "vpn-45", "vpn-81", "vpn-98"), 
Transaction_count = c(2978, 324841, 9590, 131352, 150314),  
Face_value = c(557600, 108998381, 4975880, 55503635, 54759542)),  
row.names = c(NA, -5L),  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))

##Using dplyr and base R's format function.. 
Combined %>% 
          mutate(Count_contribution = paste0(round(Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count)*100,0),"%"),
                 Transaction_count=format(Transaction_count,big.mark=","),
                 Face_value=paste0("$",format(Face_value,big.mark=",",trim=T)))
```